# Determine recycler item above center or below for a recycler view nested in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Have a recycler view nested in NestedScrollView

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<NestedScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
<RecyclerView>
```

Trying to scroll to a particular item in recycler view with below code

```
val childOffset = recyclerView.y + recyclerView.getChildAt(index).top
binding.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, childOffset.toInt())
```

Have to figure out if the scrolled element is in top part of center of screen or bottom part of screen.
How to achieve this ?

```
  val outlocation = IntArray(2)
  viewHolder.getLocationOnScreen(outlocation)
  val displayOnTop = outLocation[1] > requireContext().resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels/2
```

This approach is not working as getLocationScreen value is not being consistent with scrolling.

What is the better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve with below approach.

```
val viewHolder = recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(index)
   if (viewHolder != null) {
       val rect = Rect()
           viewHolder.getHitRect(rect) //Gets the rectangle coordinates in parent view coordinates system of the recycler item
       recyclerView.requestRectangleOnScreen(rect) //auto scroll and position item on screen with request Focus
       val displayOnTop =
               rect.bottom > (binding.nestedScrollView.top + binding.nestedScrollView.bottom) / 2
}
```